# Matlab imresize function rounding up pixels

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm looking to take in an image of 162x193 pixels and basically scale it down by 0.125 i.e 162/8 = 20.25 and 193/8 = 24.125. Thus I would like a picture of size 20x24 The only problem I'm currently having is that when I use the `imresize` function it rounds up the images pixel values i.e I get an image of size 21x25 instead of 20x24. Any way of getting 20x24 or is this problem something I'm going to have to live with? Here is some code:

```
    //Read in original Image
    imageBig = imread(strcat('train/',files(i).name));  
    //Resize the image
    image = imresize(imageBig,0.125);
    disp(size(image));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that with the `scale` argument being provided, `imresize` `ceils` up the dimensions as your results show. So, I guess an obvious choice is to manually provide it the `rounded` values as dimensions.

**Code**

```
%%// Scaling ratio
scale1 = 0.125;

%%// Get scaled up/down version
[M,N,~] = size(imageBig);
image = imresize(imageBig,[round(scale1*M) round(scale1*N)]);
```