# Resizing image in specific case

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I have an image of size `260 x 260` pixels. I know how to resize it to `140 x 140` pixels for example and then convert it to grayscale. Let us assume the matlab code below:

```
image = imread('my_image.jpg');
image_resized = imresize(image, [140 140]);
size(image_resized) % 140 x 140 x 3
image_gray = rgb2gray(image_resized);
size(image_gray) % 140 x 140
```

What I want is a specific case. I am interested to normalize the image to **140 pixels in height** where **width was rescaled accordingly so that the image aspect ratio was preserved**. Unfortunately I don't know how to edit my above code.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
image = imread('my_image.jpg');
desired_height = 140;

%%// Width of the resized image keeping the aspect ratio same as before
n2 = round((size(image,2)/size(image,1))*desired_height);

%%// Resized image
image_resized = imresize(image, [desired_height n2]);
```

**Edit 1**

**NOTE:** Alternatively you can use the size prescribed by `imresize` using NaN as suggested by Shai's solution too, but it [ceils](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/ceil.html) or rounds up the sizes, which you might not want in most of the cases.

To prove this case, I tried `imresize` to keep the height as 173, I got different sizes with manual resizing as opposed to when I let `imresize` decide the sizes.

**Code used for the experiment**

```
%%// Resized image
image_resized_with_auto_sizing  = imresize(image, [desired_height NaN]);
image_resized_with_manual_sizing  = imresize(image, [desired_height n2]);
```

The size outputs for my experiment -

```
>> whos image_resized_with_manual_sizing image_resized_with_auto_sizing
  Name                                    Size               Bytes  Class    Attributes

  image_resized_with_auto_sizing        173x185x3            96015  uint8              
  image_resized_with_manual_sizing      173x184x3            95496  uint8
```

Notice the difference in width for the two cases. This issue is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22453444/matlab-imresize-function-rounding-up-pixels) too.

Comment: why not let `imresize` figure out `n2` by itself?

Comment: @Shai Check out Edit 1, why one might think twice before letting `imresize` decide the sizes.

Comment: Ok in this case you got a width equal to 184 instead of 185 and 95496 bytes instead of 96015. Does this is an advantage by comparing to the auto sizing. So your method is more efficient?

Comment: I did `n2 = round((size(image,2)/size(image,1))*desired_height);`. If I don't `round` the value, I would have gotten `n2` as `184.0819`. Thus, the image must be `173x184.0819`. Since width can't be decimal number, so we need to choose a whole number. It makes sense to round the width to `184`, rather than ceil up to `185` as done with the case when using `NaN` as the size parameter. Read more on this at here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22453444/matlab-imresize-function-rounding-up-pixels

Comment: @Christina Try with an image that is not square, that is not `260x260` and try to resize to keep the height at a number like `173`. Then, manually calculate what must be the width based on the aspect ratio, it must get clear that way.

Comment: Yes I tried with an image of size 339 x 509, and it works well. So it is more better to round the value of width instead of ceiling it. The Shai's code is obviously more simple but your code is more efficient. (one line is just added, so it is not a big problem :))

Comment: @Christina Exactly! Just one more line :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NaN` is the desired size argument to indicate exacty what you want

```
image_resized = imresize( image, [140 NaN] );
```

Which basically tells Matlab "don't bother me with the image's width - figure it out yourself!".

See [`imresize`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html) documentation for more information.

Comment: I tried your code and the code of Divakar, and I got the same result. Does the two codes are similar but yours is much simplified ?

Comment: @Christina Check out my Edit 1, on the some of the issues with `imresize` deciding on the sizes on its own.

Comment: @Christina if you are not too picky as to how the other dimension is computed (`round`ed or `ceil`ed...) than my answer is a simplified version of what [Divakar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22656560/1714410) proposed. IMHO, using the simplified version keeps the code cleaner and easier to understand and maintain.